# Should we build complex applications on top of a CMS?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

At my latest job, we are basically told to build **stand-alone web applications** (which don't necessarily share an interface design), which in turn get accessed via a simple web portal. Since over time I have gathered quite a bit of trust, I am looking for ways to really **integrate** -at least the new, to be developed- **applications** and for which I could provide a central point of administration.

In about 5-6 weeks we will **start developing** a few private applications (employee appraisal software, help desk software, just to name a few), which is why I have started to look for alternatives to building "islands" of software.

**Should I bother** with an CMS like Umbraco? What's the learning curve on these for complex modules (I have never worked on top of a CMS)? Any other **alternatives**?

**Note:** Any solution would have to be .NET-based and behave nicely with SQL Server, Oracle and eventually PostgreSQL. Also, for budgetary and time concerns, management would never allow us to build our own CMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umbraco is a good choice for a CMS based application. It's widely used and offers great deals of flexibility.

However, keep in mind, that the reason why you are building an application on top of a CMS (Content Management System) is to leverage the out-of-the-box features of the CMS, such as:

- Abiliuty for users to change, add, remove content
- Publishing mechanism (publish from/to date)
- Integrated User (and member) authentication with proven stability
- History of content changes
- Complete power over HTML
- etc. etc.

If none of the out-of-the-box features are used in the application you are building, there are no real benefits to building on top of a standard system.

The best idea is to just look at the requested features for the application and look if some match the features of a ready made system like Umbraco.

Comment: Said features aren't important to us. How else would we have a single point of entry in terms of administration? Thanks.

Comment: If you want a central point of administration, you CAN use a CMS for central user authentication, etc. However if you're not going to use any features of the CMS except for the central login, I think it's a bit of an overkill. Just implement your own ASP.Net membership / login system.